# fetching contacts using background thread crashes the app

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am using background thread(asynctask) to fetch contacts from the phone & send it to the server using post request it works for 50 to 100 contacts but get crashed if the contacts is more than 500 or 1000, is there any other way to do this processing

Comment: what's the logcat output when it crashes ?

Comment: We need code, logcat and the line which provokes this behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create a service which runs in background and pushes contacts to server in batches.

You can solve this issue by 3 steps:

1.Create a class extending from IntentService and in the onHandleIntent() method , call the function which pushes the contacts to the server.

```
     public class ContactPushSerive extends IntentService {
       @Override
       protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
         pushContacts();    
       }
     }
```

2.The function for pushing the contacts should create batches of contacts internally and push one batch at a time. You can choose the batch size like 50 contacts in one batch.

```
     public static void pushContacts() {

                    int BATCH_SIZE = 50;

        //create getContactsFromOS() to fetch OS Contacts
        List<Contact> contactsList = getContactsFromOS();

        if (contactsList != null && contactsList.size() > 0) {

            // Batching contact push
            for (int i = 0; i < (contactsList.size() / BATCH_SIZE) + 1; i++) {
                List<Contact> subList = null;
                if ((i + 1) * BATCH_SIZE > contactsList.size()) {
                    subList = contactsList.subList(i * BATCH_SIZE, contactsList.size());
                }
                else {
                    subList = contactsList.subList(i * BATCH_SIZE, (i + 1) * BATCH_SIZE);
                }

                //push the contacts to the server using 
                pushContacts(subList);

            }
        }
      }
```

3.Call this service from your code :

```
    //time after which the service should start , currently set to 2 min
    long time = System.currentTimeMillis() + (2l * 60 * 1000);

    //create intent to invoke the ContactPushService
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, ContactPushSerive.class);

    //Start the ContactPushService after 2 min using the Pending Intent and setting the alarm to fire after 2 min
    PendingIntent contactServiceIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, -15, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    AlarmUtils.setAlarm(context, contactServiceIntent, time);
```

Comment: If i am starting an intentservice from an activity & then we move on to a different activity does the intentservice still be working

Comment: Wow great!! So if you start intentService from one activity and move to another activity , the intent service will still be working because it runs in the background independently of the activity that started it. It will stop running only when the onHandleIntent() method finishes.

Comment: @user2718007 Can you mark this as the correct answer, it will be very helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IntentService`.if you're sending data to your server, an `IntentService` is extremely helpful in this regard because you can start and forget. The user can, say, type a comment in your app then press `"send"`. `"Send"` will launch the `IntentService` which gets the comment and send it off in to your server on a background thread. If you did this with an `AsyncTask` in your `Activity` on the other hand, the system could kill off your process in the middle of your exchange and it may-or-may not go through.